# I need help trying to know when a user enters a duplicated number, without collections

Tags: java, arrays

So I am having trouble trying to find duplicates in an array where a user enters the numbers. I want to display a dialog when they enter a number that is already in the array. It sounds simple but is confused on how to go on about this.

```
//Convert the string into an int
num =  Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());

// Add it to the an index
array[index] = num;
// Increment the index variable
index++;
// If the the duplicate exists
for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
    if(array[index] == num){
        if(array[i - 1] == num){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Array may not contain duplicates ","Array Duplicate",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use a Set instead for an array, that would prohibit duplicates, and you can query it with contains

Comment: i agree, however if you insist on using an array, you have to fix the way you are looping the values ....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 

From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: @Mikenno I know but there has to be a way to do this without using collections or arraylists and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking and some suggestion. I managed to solve it.

```
               // Set orginal to true
               boolean orginal = true;
              //Convert the string into an int
              num =  Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
              // Loop to find the duplicate
              for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                  // Check if there's a duplicate
                  for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                      // Check if the num is equal to any of the numbers in the array
                      if(array[j] == num){
                          // Set orginal to false
                          orginal = false;
                          // Throw the duplicate exception
                          throw new DuplicateValueException(result);
                      }
                  }
                  // If there is no duplicates
                  if(orginal){
                      // Add the number to the array
                      array[index] = num;
                      // Break out the loop
                      break;
                  }

              }
              // Print the message
              System.out.println("array["+index+"] = "+ num);
              // Increment the index variable
              index++;
```

Comment: Much better :) just two remarks : the outer loop is not required, the boolean either (either you rise an exception or you use a boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to fix your code here

```
//Convert the string into an int
    num =  Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
    boolean exsist = false;


// If the the duplicate exists
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
        if(array[i] == num){
            exsist = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Array may not contain duplicates ","Array Duplicate",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!exsist)
    {
        // Add it to the an index
        array[index] = num;
        // Increment the index variable
        index++;
    }
```

something like this should work

The reasoning is

1. not using the variable `i` from the for loop, this results in checking the same value all the time
2. the checks in the if statements are broken, the checks simply don't make sense, try to use the `i`or other variables that change each loop to check multiple values
3. there is no need to add the value before testing if it exsist, if you do so    you will have to remove it after, doing it after therefore result in a faster code (even if only very very little) and a safer code since you can't fail to delete the value

Comment: It is a school work (as the op specifies without collections). So giving a full working code is already not a very good idea but with not a single explanation, it is really not desirable.

Comment: @davidxxx added the basic reasons for the code alternations :)

Comment: @Mikenno much better

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1;i++){
if(array[i] == num){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Array may not contain duplicates ","Array Duplicate",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
        break;

    }
}
```

Try this!

But your code will add that number to array anyway as you are adding it before checking it.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no sense :

```
// Add it to the an index
array[index] = num;
// Increment the index variable
index++;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
   if(array[index] == num){
```

You add the `num` int at the `index` index of the array and then in the loop you want to check if `index+1 == num`.
In your logic you should rather check if `index == num`.
 
And anyway it is useless, you have done : `array[index] = num;`.
So `if(array[index] == num)` can be only true.

> I want to display a dialog when they enter a number that is already in
>   the array

You should rather do the check of duplication number before adding it in the array.
The general idea would be iterating the array and if during the iteration, a element of the array is equals to `num`, you have not add `num`.
In the contrary case, if no element is equals to `num`, you have to add it.

It seems to be a school working, so I will not detail further the solution.

Comment: I see what you mean, I will give it another go. Thanks for the clear understanding.

Comment: Hey, David thank you for the suggest after looking at it a different way. I managed to figure it out. Also, I was wondering can I ask you some question about Java?

Comment: What is your advice for someone, who wants to be a Java developer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for sure even for the case of [5->5]

```
    index++;
    // If the the duplicate exists
    if (index > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == num) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Array may not contain duplicates ", "Array Duplicate", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```